# If we traveled at almost light speed with a mirror in hand

Tags: special-relativity, reflection

What would we see if we hold the mirror in front of us and behind us.

Comment: a complete lack of ether.  (Google around for what I seem to remember as being Einstein's thought experiment)

Comment: This might be interesting for you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IgAII_crHHc

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you see yourself in a mirror when you are riding on top of a light stream?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8163/)

Comment: Your face/feet?

Comment: I find this an interesting question. If nothing travels faster then light. Then how would the light catch up from the mirror in the back? The mirror in the front I would assume would not change as the light could come "back" to you, but the mirror behind would have some kind of delay as the light tried to catch up, but took longer to do so. Like flying faster then sound (with out the compression).

Comment: In modern physics, speed is binary. Either it's lightspeed or it's less than lightspeed. In your case, it's less than lightspeed. Without loss of generality, you may assume you're travelling 100 km/hour.

Comment: @coteyr: At relativistic speeds, you can no longer add up or subtract speeds as if they're simple numbers. Light coming from the mirror behind you, being light, travels with speed c towards you. Your own speed is irrelevant, it can be 99% of c or 0.00001% of c. Results are identical.

Comment: The skin ripped from your face

Comment: @MSalters, But we know it takes time for light to travel, (not saying your wrong by the way, just find the question interesting.) So if I am in a car doing 30 and I look at a mirror in the back seat of the car, the light takes time to get from the mirror to my eyes. Now at 30m/s Light is way faster then the car, so you can use the bouncy ball example. But at near light speed, the max speed is important. Light can't travel at light speed from the mirror to my eyes because that would be greater then light speed.

Comment: @coteyr: Time too behaves non-linear at those speeds. Light _does_ travel at light speeds from the mirror to your eyes. We've measured it. Look up the Michelson Morley experiment, which famously killed Ether theory (hence Carl Witthoft's comment). If the speed of the source would matter, the earth moving around the sun should matter too. It didn't.

Comment: I'm voting to re-open. The other question asks what happens at $c$. Almost at $c$ is quite different: it's possible for nonzero restmass things for one. So I think the OP wants some insight into how the images in a mirror change as we approach light speed (although the two answers do give this insight).

Comment: If you re-word your question to make the distinction clear, it may be re-opened. Also make clear what you want to know: image intensities, distortions, colour shifts? I only have one vote: four more are needed. You could try flagging it with a moderator. However, I hope you should understand that you will not see anything different by the first postulate of relativity (Galileo's postulate), broadened to light by the second postulate.

Comment: I'm also voting to reopen, because the "duplicate" question has been closed as off-topic on the grounds that it's "non-mainstream" physics. As Rod Vance says, this one avoids that by asking about being near rather than at the speed of light.

Comment: @Nathaniel: Also, the "duplicate" appears to have since been deleted.

Answer (score 9):

If you are traveling at near lightspeed, and the mirrors are traveling with you, there will be no change in the behavior of the mirrors, or any other observation you make of anything else moving at near lightspeed with you. Relativity tells that light must travel at the same speed in any reference frame, and a reference frame traveling at nearly the speed of light is no different.

Answer (score 3):

When you are traveling almost at the lightspeed, **you are moving at this speed only as compared to another frame of reference** (body). Which means that - according to the postulates of the Theory of Special Relativity - you are allowed to assume that you are not moving at all and that this other body is moving at near-lightspeed (but in the opposite direction). If the movements are inertial - as SR assumes - then there is no way to tell who is moving: you or the other body.

The conclusion is that according to SR **there can be no difference whatsoever regarding your image in the mirrors** - whether you are moving or not. If there were, you could claim that there some absolute state of rest can be found, which SR denies to exist.

So if you emit light toward any of the mirrors, and measure its speed upon the return of the beam, you will always measure $c$.

Answer (score -1):

The speed of light is completely dependent on the frame of reference you are using.  As already stated, the mirrors traveling with you are in your frame of reference and, therefore, will not be affected by the tremendous speed that you are traveling.

It may help to think of the frame of reference that you are in right now, regarding your position on Earth traveling around the sun, which is rotating around our galaxy, which is traveling through space at a tremendous speed itself.  All of this motion does not affect the speed of light being emitted from your computer screen, for example, since your computer is in your frame of reference.